# Проблема с отображением данных в ChartControl WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

Установил DataSourse в IEnumerable, в DataContext подцепил

```
        public ObservableCollection<ReportOfTransport> ReportOfTransport
    {
        get { return _reportOfTransports; }
        set { _reportOfTransports = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }
```

Но данные не отображаются

```
    <Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:dxc="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/charts" xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core" xmlns:FuelConsumptionClient="clr-namespace:FuelConsumptionClient" xmlns:DbModelClient="clr-namespace:DbModelClient;assembly=DbModelClient" x:Class="FuelConsumptionClient.Views.Analitics"
    Title="Аналітика" Height="455.224" Width="688.06">
<Window.Resources>
    <dx:IEnumerableDataSource x:Key="IEnumerableDataSource">
        <dx:DesignDataManager.DesignData>
            <dx:DesignDataSettings DataObjectType="{x:Type FuelConsumptionClient:ReportOfTransport}" RowCount="5"/>
        </dx:DesignDataManager.DesignData>
    </dx:IEnumerableDataSource>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <Binding Path="AnaliticsModel" Source="{StaticResource Locator}"/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>

    <TabControl Margin="0,9,0,0">
        <TabItem x:Name="TiUpdate" Style="{StaticResource TabItemStyle}" Header="Кількість витраченого палива по транспорту">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFF0F0FD" Offset="0.009"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF94B3DE" Offset="0.691"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Grid.Background>
                <dxc:ChartControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" DataSource="{Binding Data, Source={StaticResource IEnumerableDataSource}}" DataContext="{Binding ReportOfTransport}">
                    <dxc:ChartControl.CrosshairOptions>
                        <dxc:CrosshairOptions ShowArgumentLabels="True" ShowValueLine="True" ShowValueLabels="True"/>
                    </dxc:ChartControl.CrosshairOptions>
                    <dxc:ChartControl.Legend>
                        <dxc:Legend/>
                    </dxc:ChartControl.Legend>
                    <dxc:XYDiagram2D>
                        <dxc:XYDiagram2D.AxisX>
                            <dxc:AxisX2D>
                                <dxc:AxisX2D.Label>
                                    <dxc:AxisLabel Staggered="True"/>
                                </dxc:AxisX2D.Label>
                            </dxc:AxisX2D>
                        </dxc:XYDiagram2D.AxisX>
                        <dxc:BarSideBySideSeries2D DisplayName="Очікуваний об'єм, л" ArgumentDataMember="TransportTitle" ValueDataMember="Fuel"/>
                        <dxc:BarSideBySideSeries2D DisplayName="Фактичний об'єм, л" ArgumentDataMember="TransportTitle" ValueDataMember="ActualFuel"/>
                    </dxc:XYDiagram2D>
                </dxc:ChartControl>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem x:Name="TiAdd" Style="{StaticResource TabItemStyle}" IsEnabled="{Binding AccountingEnabled}" Header="Кількість витраченого палива по розрахунку">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFF0F0FD" Offset="0.009"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF94B3DE" Offset="0.691"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Grid.Background>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>

</Grid>
```

Comment: ошибок привязок нет? `Snoop` или если VS2015 (или старше) то в ней тоже можно посмотреть.

Comment: VS 2013. Сейчас попробую проверить

Comment: Связь между моделью и представлением работает, успешно вывел строку в label.

Comment: Я имею ввиду конкретно для `DataSource="{Binding Data, Source={StaticResource IEnumerableDataSource}}"`. Не использовал VS2013, но, кажется, там нет нужного функционала, поэтому советую поставить `Snoop` и посмотреть в нем